# Como puedo leer un archivo de Excel en visual estudio 2015 y c#

Tags: c#

Alguien me puede orientar gracias .[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lee [ask], la imagen no es de mucho apoyo pues no es legible

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor, no publiques imágenes con código fuente, copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por las correcciones es  primera vez que utilizó la plataforma, soy principiante y e estado buscando pero no encuentro como. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public   DataTable CargarDesdeExcel(string ruta)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        // Dim conn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & ruta & ";Persist Security Info=False;" 'Se crea la cadena de conexion ole
        string conn = "";
        List<string> Extenciones =new List<string>(){".xlsx","xlsx"}.ToList();

        if (Path.GetExtension(ruta).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ruta + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        else if (Path.GetExtension(ruta).ToLower() == ".xls")
            conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + ruta + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection olConexion = new OleDbConnection(conn))
            {
                olConexion.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                dt = olConexion.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });      // Cargamos en una tabla todo el excel
                string nombreHoja = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();                                                      // Se obtiene nombre de la primera hoja del documento
                cmdExcel.Connection = olConexion;
                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + nombreHoja + "]";                                                         // Seleccion de todo lo que contiene esa hoja
                oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                oda.Fill(dtExcel);                                                                                                   // Llenamos el adaptador
                olConexion.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return dtExcel;
    }
```

Espero te Sirva

Comment: Trata de no dar respuestas a preguntas que incumplan las reglas de la comunidad. Saludos!

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).